# How to calculate $ \int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (x t)+x\sin(x t)}{1+x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

In calculating the inverse Fourier transform of $$F(\omega)=\frac{1}{1+i\omega}$$
I ended up with calculating
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (x t)+x\sin(x t)}{1+x^2}\,dx\tag{*}
$$
Mathematica says:

> [image]

How could one calculate (*) by hand?

Comment: I believe the fourier transform of $e^{-at} u(t)$ is $\frac{1}{a+ i w}$.

Comment: @MathLover: that's the Fourier transform for the one-sided decaying exponential. I'm interested in known how one would calculate ($*$) without knowing *a priori* it is related to the Fourier transform of a known function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.
You can start by noticing
$$I(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i x t}}{1+x^2}dx=2
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+x^2}dx.$$
and $$J(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{i x t}}{1+x^2}dx=2i
\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(xt)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

Now note that $J(t) = -i I'(t)$ and thus your integral can be written as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)+x \sin(x t)}{1+x^2}dx= \frac12 [I(t)-i J(t)] =\frac12 [I(t)- I'(t)].$$

It is a simple exercise using the residue theorem to show that
$$I(t) =\pi e^{-|t|} $$
and thus to show that
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(xt)+x \sin(x t)}{1+x^2}dx =\frac\pi2 e^{-|t|} [1+\operatorname{sgn}(t)] $$

Answer (score 4):

Consider
$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x(\beta^2+x^2)}\,dx$$
Then we have

$$I'=\frac{\partial I}{\partial\alpha}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos \alpha x}{\beta^2+x^2}\,dx$$

and

$$I''=\frac{\partial^2I}{\partial \alpha^2}=-\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin \alpha x}{\beta^2+x^2}\,dx$$

It is easy to show that

$$I''-\beta^2I=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

where we use the fact

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\alpha x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Solving  the second-order linear ODE using initial conditions  $I(0)=0$ and $I'(0)=\frac{\pi}{2\beta}$, one may  deduce

$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\pi\left(1-e^{-\alpha\beta}\right)}{2\beta^2}$$

and

$$I'(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\partial  I}{\partial\alpha}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos \alpha  x}{\beta^2+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{-\alpha\beta}}{2\beta}$$

Thus, setting $\alpha=t$ and $\beta=1$, we have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos xt}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{-t}}{2}$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin xt}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

can be evaluated by evaluating $I''(\alpha,1)$ and setting $\alpha=t$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach comes from the Laplace transform. We have
$$\mathcal{L}(\cos x)=\frac{s}{s^2+1},\qquad \mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$
[hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis), assuming $t>0$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(xt)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\mathcal{L}\sin(xt)\right)(s)\,\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)(s)\,ds $$
(the LHS is converging by Dirichlet's test, since $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is decreasing towards zero from some point on and $\sin(xt)$ has a bounded primitive) leads to:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(xt)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\cos(s)}{t^2+s^2}\,ds\stackrel{s\mapsto tx}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx $$
so we just need to compute:
$$ 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx\stackrel{\text{parity}}{=}\text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{isx}}{x^2+1}\,dx $$
and by the residue theorem the last integral equals
$$ \text{Re}\left[2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{itx}}{x^2+1},x=i\right)\right]=\text{Re}\left[2\pi i\lim_{x\to i}\frac{e^{itx}}{x+i}\right]=\pi e^{-t}. $$
For $t=0$ the given integral clearly equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and for $t<0$ the same manipulations show the given integral equals zero. Summarizing,

> $$ \forall t\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(xt)+x\sin(xt)}{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|t|}\left(1+\text{sign }t\right).$$